# How to know total number of installations of my android application?

Tags: android, cordova, apk, developer-console

I want to know total number of installations of my android application, I can see the total download, if the application was installed through Playstore but I want to know the total installs including transferred through Shareit, Xender or other applications...

Comment: create one API in which you have to pass device id which will be unique and execute that API in splash screen. It will give you list of users by device. And API execute once.

Comment: google play statistics

Answer (score 1):

i use easy way to detect my app installations and many more details..

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/android/

flurry analytics gives you all the desired details faster then Google Playstore.

and output sample :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should place a code than will increase a counter everytime your app was installed and used for the first time. For this you will need a server and a database that will keep this info registred. If you want I will provide this code for you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such API present, instead you should write your own custom API that will transmit the details to your server from your api, for android you can get IMEI of device will be unique.

More so, if you have Push notifications integrated in your app, you can api count that will transmit the time when the app has been opened, that log  will give you **count of active users of the app**  which will be precise count of the users using your app, since in first approach you will get lifetime count, not the active count

Comment: @HimanshuMori In that case for push notification based approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use [Fabric](https://fabric.io/login) developed by twitter. It is very fast and very easy to integrate.